# Object code relocation and Intel Pin interaction

Tags: c++, gcc, ld, glibc, intel-pin

I am working on a multiprocessor architectural simulator that uses Intel Pin to instrument C++ executable binaries and report interesting events (e.g., some function calls, thread create/finish, etc.). Basically, I build an  instruction-decode cache of all instructions when their images are loaded and analyze instruction execution afterwards. So it is important for instruction addresses at image-load time to be the same as (or at least get updated synchronously with) instruction addresses at run-time.

Intel Pin API (e.g., IMG_AddInstrumentFunction) enables me to get information about the loaded images (executables and shared libraries) such as entry points, low/high address, etc.

However, I noticed that the instrumented program executes instructions at addresses that do not belong to any of the loaded images. By inspection, I am suspecting that the dynamic loader (image /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 on ***64-bit Centos 6.3***) is relocating the main executable in memory by calling routine **_dl_relocate_object**.

I understand the need for relocatable code and all that stuff. I just need pointers to a good documentation (or just a brief description/advice) on how/when these relocations might happen (at load-time and runtime) so that I can take them into account in my architectural simulator. In other words, the ***mechanism*** used to achieve it (library functions that I need to instrument, conditions, or maybe randomization if there is any, g++ compiler switches that can be used to suppress relocation, etc).
P.S.: I am only targeting x86/x86_64 architectures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relocation are processor specific, so ARM and x86-64 and x86 have different relocations (because their instruction set is different).

<sup>Relocation are also operating system specific, but some related OSes try to have the same relocations, e.g. Solaris and Linux for x86-64</sup>

They are described in detail in the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (application binary interface) specification *"System V Application Binary Interface AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement"*. The original x86-64 ABI used to be on http://www.x86-64.org/documentation.html 
but that site is not responding since several weeks. An old copy is on [this link](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/devel/assembly/abi_sysV_amd64.pdf) and a newer one is [here](http://ensiwiki.ensimag.fr/images/d/de/System_V_Application_Binary_Interface_AMD64_Architecture_Processor_Supplement.pdf)

There is also the [X32 ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI)

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5554856/841108).

Comment: Thanks, Basile. I am just still not permitted to upvote your answer because my votes are less than 15.